# Find the number of factors of some number which are perfect squares

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The problem is
"Find the number of factors of the product $5^8 \cdot 7^5 \cdot 2^3$ which are perfect squares"

With a simple google search, the answer is happened to be 30 but I don't have any idea how.

Comment: Are you sure it's $30$? Taking a look at the prime factorization, the answer is pretty obviously $2$. ([Link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=prime+factorization+58+*+75+*+23+))

Comment: $30$ may be the total number of divisors of that number, but most of those $30$ divisors aren't perfect squares. Wait – is 58*75*23 supposed to be $5^87^52^3$?

Comment: Hints: what can you say about the prime factorization of a factor of your number? what can you say about the prime factorization of a perfect square?

Comment: @EeveeTrainer Yes, at first I use the prime factorization and found the answer to be 2 too. But this problem actually has multiple choice which is 35, 40, 20, 30, 25. So 2 is not one of them. Of course there is the possibility that the multiple choice is wrong.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Oh, that can be the case actually. How to close the question?

Comment: I am editing the question @Calendar. If it is correct, pls approve the edit.

Comment: Don't close it, Calendar; answer it!

Comment: Think about this: How can you tell from just the prime factorization of a number that it is a perfect square?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well if you see perfect squares can only be made when any number has an even power.

In this example here how many even powers does each of the prime numbers 2 , 5 , 7 have?

There are 5 even powers for 5 (0,2,4,6,8) , 3 even powers for 7 (0,2,4) and 2 even powers for 2 (0,2) . So in total, using the fundamental principle of counting the total perfect square factors of this number are simply:

$5*3*2 = 30  , \text{which matches the answer .} $

Hope this helps.